# Understanding jQuery effects queueing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, effects

I'm trying to have one jQuery effect/animation run after another.  I've tried this:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({'left':'+=300'},1000).delay(2000).animate({'left':'-=300'},1000);
```

**EDIT:**

This actually does work- just a pasting mistake on my part.  Chaining effects automatically creates a queue, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), which is what we want:

> `$('#foo').slideUp().fadeIn();`
>
> When this statement is executed, the
>   element begins its sliding animation
>   immediately, but the fading transition
>   is placed on the fx queue to be called
>   only once the sliding transition is
>   complete.

(Thanks for the help, won't let me delete the question)

Comment: Your understanding of the docs is correct. What you have should work. Here's an example. http://jsbin.com/eladu3/ Is there any chance you copy/pasted the code from somewhere? Sometimes invalid invisible characters find their way in and break the code.

Comment: Sure enough- it does work, stupid pasting mistake- ... won't let me delete the question though...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a call back parameter

with it you can do this

```
$('#myDiv').animate({'left':'+=300'},1000, function () {
   //Start Next Animation
   $(this).animate({'left':'-=300'},1000, function () {
     //Start Next animation
   });
})
```

Comment: I know about callbacks, but I want to chain rather than nest, and this also doesn't provide any easy way for delays.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this: using the [`callback`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) parameter to animate, and using [queues](http://api.jquery.com/queue).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `position: absolute;` (or `relative`, depending on what you want) on the div?  If you didn't then animating `left` won't do anything.  Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vftNF/

Comment: I was thinking something similar at first, but the question states *"the separate animation calls work by themselves"*.

Comment: Well, did you check out the example?  That works for me, so you can use that to compare with whatever code you have.

Comment: Nevermind, I saw your comment.  But note that you can save some bandwidth/typing by not putting quotes around the parameters: `{left: '+=300'}`